# Trying to connect to HTTPS site via IP (with known hostname) in PHP, getting "Peer certificate ... does not match expected CN ..."

Tags: php, ssl, dns

I'm writing a CLI PHP script that will connect to a server to fetch and process some data. The system it's running on sometimes has slow Internet, so I wanted to add some verbosity into the script to show DNS lookup, connect, etc.

So, I switched from using plain `file_get_contents()` and made the extra effort to create a TCP socket, manually send HTTP data, etc, so I can intersperse these discrete operations with status updates.

However, the initial DNS-lookup-and-connect can still take up to 5 seconds, with most of that due to random slowness from 8.8.8.8. So, I decided to see if I could get in between the DNS lookup and the actual connect call:

```
$ip = gethostbyname('google.com.');

$stream = stream_socket_client('tls://'.$ip.':443/');
```

Well, unfortunately...

```text
PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): Peer certificate CN=`*.google.com' did not 
match expected CN=`216.58.196.142' in ...

PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto in ...

PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tls://216.58.196.142:443/
(Unknown error) in ...
```

...this causes PHP's TLS stack to freak out. **Which is entirely appropriate, configured correctly, and not a bug** as it's only seeing the IP address and not the hostname and it has legitimate reason to get indigestion.

(...Although PHP should ***not*** then go and summarize "this could be a MITM attack" as "Unknown error"... facepalm; but I digress.)

My fundamental problem is that neither curl, sockets or streams provide me event callbacks that describe "about to connect", "doing DNS lookup", "connected", etc etc notifications. :(

Comment: does this remote site allow such actions?

Comment: @nogad: What do you mean? It's a standard HTTPS server. In the test I'm doing I'm using google.com, which is effectively equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to reimplement HTTPS via PHP streams. We shouldn't have to explain why this is a bad idea.

1. If you want to skip DNS lookups then use `/etc/hosts`. [super bad idea]
2. Don't skip DNS, that's a super bad idea.

   Neither PHP nor most Linux distros implement local DNS resolvers/caches which usually results in hammering whatever DNS server your PHP app is pointed at, and bad performance if you're pointing to a crappy DNS server. [though in your case I'll bet you're getting throttled because hammering]

   So either:

   1. Point caching resolver located somewhere inside your local network, eg: your provider's.
   2. Install a simple caching DNS resolver on the machine, eg: nscd, dnsmasq, or bind.

   And if you *still* have DNS latency problems  after this then the sane thing to do is to escalate this problem to your provider.